# How to speed up the time taken by mysql queries made in one table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `visit` with about 3.500.000 rows in it.
Scheme is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `visit`;
CREATE TABLE `visit` (
  `VisitId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `VisitorId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ApplicationId` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `Timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`VisitId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `VisitId-index` (`VisitId`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `VisitVisitor` (`VisitorId`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `VisitTimestamp` (`Timestamp`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `VisitTestIndex` (`ApplicationId`,`Timestamp`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `VisitTestIndex2` (`VisitorId`,`ApplicationId`,`Timestamp`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK-visit-application` FOREIGN KEY (`ApplicationId`) REFERENCES `application` (`ApplicationId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `visit-visitor` FOREIGN KEY (`VisitorId`) REFERENCES `visitor` (`VisitorId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

A simple query like

```
SELECT visit.`VisitorId`, visit.`TimeStamp` FROM visit WHERE (visit.`ApplicationId` = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
```

is very slow (50-60 seconds). What can I do to speed this up?

Comment: Could you share the `explain` results?

Comment: hi @thewildmoose use an explain plan like [that](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/) to have a better understanding of your query.

Comment: @Andy K - there is a composite index **KEY `VisitTestIndex` (`ApplicationId`,`Timestamp`) USING BTREE,**

Comment: @DarshanMehta explain returns: 

select_type: simple
table: visit
possible_keys: VisitTestIndex
key: VisitTestIndex
key_len: 108
ref: const
rows: 1670860
extra: Using index condition